# Python: Way to build a dictionary with a variable key and append to a list as the value inside a loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap

I have a list of dictionaries. I want to loop through this list of dictionary and for each specific name (an attribute inside each dictionary), I want to create a dictionary where the key is the name and the value of this key is a list which dynamically appends to the list in accordance with a specific condition.

For example, I have

```py
d = [{'Name': 'John', 'id': 10},
     {'Name': 'Mark', 'id': 21},
     {'Name': 'Matthew', 'id': 30},
     {'Name': 'Luke', 'id': 11},
     {'Name': 'John', 'id': 20}]
```

I then built a list with only the names using names=[i['Name'] for i in dic1] so I have a list of names. Notice John will appear twice in this list (at the beginning and end). Then, I want to create a for-loop (for name in names), which creates a dictionary 'ID' that for its value is a list which appends this id field as it goes along.

So in the end I'm looking for this ID dictionary to have:

```
John: [10,20]
Mark: [21]
Matthew: [30]
Luke: [11]
```

Notice that John has a list length of two because his name appears twice in the list of dictionaries.

But I can't figure out a way to dynamically append these values to a list inside the for-loop. I tried:

```
 ID={[]} #I also tried with just {}
 for name in names: 
            ID[names].append([i['id'] for i in dic1 if i['Name'] == name])
```

Please let me know how one can accomplish this. Thanks.

Comment: You need a blank line before a code block for it to format properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
out = defaultdict(list)
for item in dic1:
    out[item['Name']].append(item['id'])
print(dict(out))
```

Or, without any imports:

```py
out = {}
for item in dic1:
    out[item['Name']] = out.get(item['Name'], []) + [item['id']]
print(out)
```

Or, with a list comprehension:

```py
out = {}
[out.update({item['Name']: out.get(item['Name'], []) + [item['id']]}) for item in dic1]
print(out)
```

Output:

```py
{'John': [10, 20], 'Mark': [21], 'Matthew': [30], 'Luke': [11]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't loop over the list of names and go searching for every one in the list; that's very inefficient, since you're scanning the whole list all over again for every name. Just loop over the original list once and update the ID dict as you go.  Also, if you build the ID dict *first*, then you can get the list of names from it and avoid another list traversal:

```
names = ID.keys()
```

The easiest solution for ID itself is a dictionary with a default value of the empty list; that way `ID[name].append` will work for names that aren't in the dict yet, instead of blowing up with a `KeyError`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
ID = defaultdict(list)
for item in d:
    ID[item['Name']].append(item['id'])
```

You can treat a defaultdict like a normal dict for almost every purpose, but if you need to, you can turn it into a plain dict by calling `dict` on it:

```
plain_id = dict(ID)
```

[The Thonnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18746959/the-thonnu) has [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73196749/797049) using `get` and list concatenation which works without `defaultdict`. Here's another take on a no-`import` solution:

```
ID = {}
for item in d:
    name, number = item['Name'], item['id']
    if name in ID:
        ID[name].append(number)
    else:
        ID[name] = [ number ]
```

Comment: Thank you. This resolves it. I wasn't thinking of using the defaultdict class. I'm guessing there is no way to accomplish this without using the defaultdict class, correct?

Comment: Sure you can; you just need some conditional logic to detect whether the name is already in the dict. See The Thonnu's answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
dic1 = [{'Name': 'John', 'id': 10}, {'Name': 'Mark', 'id': 21}, {'Name': 'Matthew', 'id': 30}, {'Name': 'Luke', 'id': 11}, {'Name': 'John', 'id': 20}]

id_dict = {}
for dic in dic1:
    key = dic['Name']
    if key in id_dict:
        id_dict[key].append(dic['id'])
    else:
        id_dict[key] = [dic['id']]

print(id_dict)   # {'John': [10, 20], 'Mark': [21], 'Matthew': [30], 'Luke': [11]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this to initiate a dictionary with a default value. In this case the default value will be empty list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
for item in dic1:
    d[item['Name']].append(item['id'])
```

Output

```
{'John': [10, 20], 'Mark': [21], 'Matthew': [30], 'Luke': [11]} # by converting (not required) into pure dict dict(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a easy version

```py
dic1=[{'Name': 'John', 'id':10}, {'Name': 'Mark', 'id':21},{'Name': 'Matthew', 'id':30}, {'Name': 'Luke', 'id':11}, {'Name': 'John', 'id':20}]
names=[i['Name'] for i in dic1]
ID = {}
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    if name in ID:
        ID[name].append(dic1[i]['id'])
    else:
        ID[name] = [dic1[i]['id']]
print(ID)
```